# SimpleSAMLPHP redirection loop

Tags: php, mysql, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

we are trying to setup sso with custom mysql database but it is going into endless loop between below two requests.

```
POST http://192.168.0.15/simplesaml/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php
```

**Set-Cookie**

```
PHPSESSID=d0eaabb959ffeb2a0dd20f4744945f8f; path=/; HttpOnly
SimpleSAMLAuthToken=_297a91e9a4e14c61d247427063201a39587396c2e3; path=/; httponly

http://192.168.0.15/simplesaml/module.php/core/loginuserpass.php?AuthState=_e3e75218660095b936b9582356bcbc7b1e26934876%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.15%2Fsimplesaml%2Fmodule.php%2Fcore%2Fas_login.php%3FAuthId%3Dexample-sql%26ReturnTo%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F192.168.0.2%252F%252Fver06%252Fapp.php
```

**Set-Cookie**

```
PHPSESSID=92688949c724d39e673eec73b0674de0; path=/; HttpOnly
```

`192.168.0.15` is our sso server and `192.168.0.2` is the website which is requesting for sso.

Are we missing anything? also is there any client and server separation of sso modules for ease of use.

Also we are not getting log file generated. permissions verified on folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check following parameters in the `config.php` file.

```
'baseurlpath' => 'http[s]://YOUR_DOMAIN/simplesaml/',
'session.cookie.domain' => '.YOUR_DOMAIN',
'session.cookie.secure' => true, // ACCORDING TO YOUR REQUIREMENT
'session.phpsession.savepath' => '/PATH/TO/STORE/SESSION', // MAKE SURE THIS PATH IS WRITABLE BY WEB/APP SERVER  
'session.phpsession.httponly' => true, // ACCORDING TO YOUR REQUIREMENT
```

Comment: Good points to set, but does not solve the redirect loop :(

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and for me, the reason was in NGINX configurations.
The NGINX wasn't listening to the /simplesaml and didn't redirect it to the right file.

```
location ^~ /simplesaml {
    alias /var/www/html/vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/www/;
    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $args;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had `session.cookie.domain` set to the wrong domain (which also triggered a redirection loop).