# simpleSAMLphp and Azure gives me "AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application"

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, saml, simplesamlphp

I am a novice for Azure SSO so I might have missed some obvious things here - please have that in mind ;-)

I need to integrate my application to Azure Active Directory. There is not much help to get in our organisation for that so I am left for myself to find the problem here :-/ My exact problem is that when I login then I get this error from Azure:

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the 
reply URLs configured for the application: 'https://192.168.0.1/secure/'.
```

I have of course searched for how to solve this myself but I didn't find anything that could get me any closer.

I have this setup:

- IIS
- PHP
- simpleSAMLphp
- Azure AD

I have not setup nor access to the Azure part as this is setup by our IT guys but they have setup this:

```
Basic SAML Configuration

Identifier (Entity ID)                      : https://192.168.0.1/secure/
Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL)  : https://192.168.0.1/secure/
Sign on URL                                 : Optional
Relay State                                 : Optional
Logout URL                                  : Optional
```

I have recived a federation XML file from Azure and have converted/populated that in to the simpleSAMLphp file **\metadata\saml20-idp-remote.php**

I have setup the **\config\authsources.php** file:

```
'entityID'                   => "https://192.168.0.1/secure/",
'idp'                        => "https://sts.windows.net/06dg12k9-1wl2-4mue-79gh-40ff1a8dnd4a/",
'NameIDFormat'               => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',
'simplesaml.nameidattribute' => 'eduPersonTargetedID',
```

Everything has been configured with this guide in mind, https://www.lewisroberts.com/2015/09/05/single-sign-on-to-azure-ad-using-simplesamlphp/

When I launch https://192.168.0.1/simpleSAMLphp/www/ and go to **Authentication** and **Test configured authentication sources** and I test with **default-sp** then I do get an Azure login screen. If I view the URL for that then it looks like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/0ad94219-6af5-474e-99d0-60f9188f3fce/saml2
    ?SAMLRequest=f[CUT]2Fy%2Fi%2Bjc%3D
    &RelayState=https%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.1%2FsimpleSAMLphp%2Fwww%2Fmodule.php%2Fcore%2Fauthenticate.php%3Fas%3Ddefault-sp
```

I assume the **RelayState** is where the request comes from on my server. I have tried to setup the **Entity ID** and **Reply URL** in Azure to be https://192.168.0.1/simpleSAMLphp/www/module.php/core/authenticate.php?as=default-sp but with the same result.

So I have provided everything I know here but I am really blank on how to fix this problem? Do I need to configure a **Reply URL** in simpleSAMLphp so it is passed as an URL parameter?

Any help would really be appreciated.

---

**### UPDATE 1 - another problem ###**

After revising the logfile from simpleSAMLphp then it showed what was sent to Azure:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_25e3fb2" Version="2.0"  Destination="https://login.microsoftonline.com/088f3fce/saml2" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://192.168.0.1/simpleSAMLphp/www/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST">
<saml:Issuer>https://192.168.0.1/simpleSAMLphp/www/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp</saml:Issuer>
<samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" AllowCreate="true"/>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

I then took the `AssertionConsumerServiceURL` from there and used that as **Reply URL** in Azure. Also I took the **Entity ID** from the simpleSAMLphp Federation page and **now the simpleSAMLphp demo page works** :-)

So my Azure setup now looks like this:

Basic SAML Configuration

```
Identifier (Entity ID)                      : https://192.168.0.1/simpleSAMLphp/www/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp
Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL)  : https://192.168.0.1/simpleSAMLphp/www/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp
Sign on URL                                 : Optional
Relay State                                 : Optional
Logout URL                                  : Optional
```

(note the difference in the URL)

However I sadly still have problems. When I have a PHP file in my web scope with this content:

```
<?PHP
require_once ("../../simpleSAMLphp/lib/_autoload.php");
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');
$as->requireAuth();

$attributes = $as->getAttributes();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($attributes);
echo '</pre>';

// Get a logout URL
$url = $as->getLogoutURL();
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($url) . '">Logout</a>';

?>
```

Then it ends up in an **infinite loop** redirecting between my server and Azure!? Viewing the log provide no major insight for me. It seems that I do receive data from Azure and that I am authenticated as I can see the user attributes in the debug log but ... if I am authenticated then why am I redirected back to Azure!?

---

**### UPDATE 2 - solution ###**

After a few more hours of looking in the simpleSAMLphp logfile and cleaning out the WARNINGS (they are actually important) then I found out that my infinite redirection was caused by a mismatch between the PHP sessions and simpleSAMLphp sessions.

My solution was to align the two and have the exact same settings all places. Make sure to check the `php.ini` session settings and the `\config\config.php` session settings and make them identical.

Also I found out that the PHP source code I have used is for an older version of simpleSAMLphp though I don't think it was a problem.

Instead of this old method:
`$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');`

Then it should be this new method:
`$as = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');`

Comment: I've seen this when the SP server was out of disk space, so it couldn't write session data. Possibly a permissions problem, not writing to disk? The docs have an extra cleanup step after requireAuth(), not sure if that's relevant https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp-api#section_3

Comment: You could also try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443704/simplesamlphp-redirection-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RelayState` is just a parameter that is echoed back to your SP as-is. It can be used to store the page url the user tried to access before authentication, for example.

If you're using `SAML2`, the replyURL should be your `AssertionConsumerService` url in your SP metadata. Azure will send the `SAML` `Response` there. If that url differs from `https://192.168.0.1/secure/` you will get that error. Even a missing trailing `/` will cause the error.

Comment: I will give a point for this as I think the `AssertionConsumerService` solved the problem. I have updated my post as I now have another problem which may or may not be related.